# Unable to Refresh the RecyclerView after deleteing an Item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

> I am successfully deleting an Item from the recyclerView. The Items gets deleted successfully, but the recyclerView is not refreshed after the delete operation.

> This is my `Adapter` code :

```
holder.removeProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            SharedPreferences myPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("loginToken", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            getToken = myPrefs.getString("token", null);

            new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                    .setTitle("Remove from Cart")
                    .setMessage("Are you sure you want to remove this Item from cart ?")
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            deleteDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "",
                                    "Please Wait...", true);

                            final RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
                            StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                                    REMOVE_CART_URL + "?token=" + getToken + "&product_id=" + cartModel.getProductid()
                                    , new Response.Listener<String>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(String response) {
                                    try {
                                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                                        String message = jsonObject.getString("success");
                                        if (message.equals("true")) {

                                            Toast.makeText(context, "Item Deleted Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                        } else {
                                            Toast.makeText(context, "Some error occurred, Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                        }

                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                        Log.e("Delete error", e.getLocalizedMessage());
                                    }

                                    deleteDialog.dismiss();

                                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                                }
                            },
                                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                                            Toast.makeText(context, "Some error occurred, Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            deleteDialog.dismiss();
                                        }
                                    });
                            requestQueue.add(request);


                        }
                    })

                    // A null listener allows the button to dismiss the dialog and take no further action.
                    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null)
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_delete)
                    .show();

        }
    });
```

> The Item after deletion stays there until I close the App and reopen. How do I fix this , so I dont have to reopen app everytime.

Comment: From the looks of things it seems like you've deleted the item from the server but not removed it from the data set that's backing this Adapter.

Comment: @IvanWooll Yes, thats the case. How do I update the recylerview

Comment: try `notifyItemRemoved(position);`

Comment: @Sniffer where. In which Line, pls epxlain a little bit

Comment: before `deleteDialog.dismiss();`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `notifyDataSetChanged()` write this code:

```
    if (yourAdapterList.size() > 0) {
        ourAdapterList.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }
```

Comment: It worked. But, now I am getting this error: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1  , How can I fix this

Comment: you must check size of your list before notify:

`if (yourAdapterList.size() > 0)
    notifyItemRemoved(position);`

I will edit that code.

Comment: Its still crashing with this message :     java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
  What to do buddy

Comment: no luck, what to do ?

Comment: Dis you test this?

`if (yourAdapterList.size() > 0) {
        ourAdapterList.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }`

Comment: yes, still the same issue

Comment: Can I see your changed code?

Comment: Here, I posted the entire Adapter code : https://pastebin.com/RSteFwp1

Comment: Your link is not opened.
test this:
 Delete `notifyDataSetChanged();` and in the onResponse before `Toast.makeText(context, "Item Deleted Successfully" ... ` write that code :
`if (yourAdapterList.size() > 0) {
        ourAdapterList.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }`